# Simplify complicated if statement

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This following code is taken from [Backbone.js Events#off()](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L118)

How can I simplify the IF part so it's easy to understand ?

```
for (i = list.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    if (!(callback && list[i] !== callback || context && list[i + 1] !== context)) {
        list.splice(i, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Err, they are storing 2 different types in the array rather than making a new type and storing array of that type alone... sigh.

Comment: I've seen more complicated `if` logic than that by far. I don't get your grouping on the tests, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some boolean maths:

```
!(callback && list[i] !== callback || context && list[i + 1] !== context)
!(!(!callback || list[i] === callback) || !(!context || list[i + 1] === context))
(!callback || list[i] === callback) && (!context || list[i + 1] === context)
```

I think the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) is much easier to understand than the negated [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

To make the single parts easier to understand, use speaking variable names (I don't know the scope of this, you may find something better):

```
var rightCallback = !callback || list[i] === callback;
var rightContext = !context || list[i + 1] === context;
if (rightCallback && rightContext) {…}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var noCallback = callback && list[i] !== callback;
var noContext = context && list[i + 1] !== context;
if(! noCallback && ! noContext){...}
```

Or to remove negations as advised in the comments :

```
var callbackCheck = !callback || list[i] === callback;
var contextCheck = !context || list[i + 1] === context;
if(callbackCheck && contextCheck ){...}
```

Comment: this works, however it doesn't make it easier to understand, with all the negations.

Comment: only that this overwrites the variables now, use some names like `validCallback` - you've got my upvote already :-)

Comment: Woops I went a little to fast.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to encapsulate the statement into a function with a descriptive name (I don't understand what you want to do), and then call

```
if (true == meaningfulConditionName(list, callback))
{
    list.splice(i, 2);
}
```

Comment: Don't use yoda conditions and never check a boolean variable for equalitiy to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Can't be simplified more than this:

```
for (i = list.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) callback && list[i] !== callback || context && list[i + 1] !== context || list.splice(i, 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my version, passed all Backbone.js tests, and would be slower than the original

```
  if(
      // callback defined, context is null
      // remove callback for all context
      ( callback && list[i] === callback
         && !context)

      // callback defined and context is defined
      // ie remove specified callback for specified context
      || ( callback && list[i] === callback
           && context && list[i+1] === context)

      // callback NOT defined and context is defined
      // ie removed all callback for specific context
      || ( !callback && list[i] !== callback
           && context && list[i+1] === context )

      // callback NOT defined and context NOT defined
      // i.e. removed everything, this is unreachable code
      // as it is caught by 
      // https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L112
      // and https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L103
      || ( !callback && !context )

      ) {

            // remove callback and context
            list.splice( i, 2 );
  }
```

Comment: This seems far less clear to me, and it doesn't match the logic in the original code. In the original, if there's no `callback` and no `context`, the `splice` will happen. In yours, it'll won't.

Comment: thanks for spotting it, i've added (!callback && !context) check, and this would be unreachable code.

Comment: Wow, a full disjunctive normal form!